# UseEffect but Only Update Certain Child in React Componet

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a complex `App` component with several children. I'd like to update some of these children (`ShouldUpdate`) when my variable `localStorageLayouts` changes, so naturally I reach for `useEffect()`, and add `localStorageLayouts` as a dependency. The problem is that useEffect causes *all* children to update, and I only need my `ShouldUpdate` component to re-render. What are some work arounds to only render the components I need updated?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useStoreState, useStoreActions } from "./hooks";
export default function App() {
  const localStorageLayouts = useStoreState(
    (state) => state.appData.localStorageLayouts
  );
    const [availableLayouts, setAvailableLayouts] = useState(localStorageLayouts);
    useEffect(() => {
      setAvailableLayouts(localStorageLayouts);
    }, [localStorageLayouts]);

    return (
        //...
        <div>
        <VeryExpensiveToRender/>
        <ShouldUpdate layouts = {availableLayouts}/>
        <OkNotToUpdate/>
        <ShouldUpdate layouts = {availableLayouts}/>
        <OkNotToUpdate/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: If you have expensive and complicated logic, I think that's what Memoization is for. https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: i think moving state down to the components that really need it is a viable option (https://overreacted.io/before-you-memo/), maybe together with a custom effect hook, so you don't have too much code duplication